# where else are .desktop files for autostart are stored?

Tags: xfce, .desktop, autostart

In my `xfce4-session-settings` there are some autostart entries to which I couldn't find the corresponding .desktop files neither in `~/.config/autostart/` nor in `/etc/xdg/autostart`

I wonder where else are autostart entries stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `catfish` search yielded the following results in my Xubuntu 16.04:

[image]

Comment: that's it, found the ones I was looking for in `usr/share/upstart/xdg/autostart/`